# Prevent Node.js websocket connection from opening (ws library)

Tags: node.js, web, websocket, ws

Is there any way to prevent ws connection from even opening?

Currently I'm using this solution:

```
wss.on('connection', (ws, request) => {
  console.log('connection opened')
  ws.on('close', () => console.log('connection closed'})
});

server.on('upgrade', async (request, socket, head) => {

  if (websocketVerificationFailed()) {
    socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
    socket.destroy();
    return;
  }

  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, ws => wss.emit('connection', ws, request));
});
```

The problem is that connection opens for a very short time, then it closes. This is not what I want, because client should not trigger onopen without verifying.

Do I need to set some timeout on client and to wait for connection status to be right or there is another way to fix it on server?

I'm using ws library, as you can see.

Comment: In my opinion, you should only allow access from a user when is he for example logged. Or in some protected route. So there is no open connection for a moment. Only if it is authorized.

Comment: Thank you, I've should went into that direction :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should only allow access from a user when is he for example logged. Or in some protected route. So there is no open connection for a moment. Only if it is authorized.